# Smallest/largest numbers program, input must stop once negative number is inserted

Tags: python, input, numbers

The purpose of this program is to find the smallest and largest values in a list. The moment the user inputs a negative number, the program should stop. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
user_inputs = []
number = int(input())

for i in range(number):
    value = int(input())
    if i >= 0:
        user_inputs.append(value)
    else:
        break

print(min(user_inputs))
print(max(user_inputs))
```

As you can see, I am new to programming and still struggling to find the logic behind loops. Surely, this code is ridden with mistakes and any helpful improvements is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother one mistake that you have done is that you are using

```
for i in range(number):
```

basically by doing this you are telling compiler that repeat the code in for loop for     "number" of times and obviously number would change every time user inputs a new number resulting in error
The right way to make the code do what you want is  :

```
user_inputs = []
while True:
   number = int(input('Enter a positive number : '))
   if number >= 0 :
      user_inputs.append(number)
   else:
      print(user_inputs)
      print('Smallest number in list is : ',min(user_inputs))
      print('Largest number in list is : ',max(user_inputs))
      break
```

Here while loop will run continuously until a negative number has been input, so when a negative number is input the while loop woulb break .

Answer (score 0):

You are checking

***i***

when you should be checking

*value*

Answer (score 0):

you have to compare value
i.e. if value >= 0
you are using i which is the number of iteration